# A sequence with interesting converging and diverging properties

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to find a sequence such that the summation of $a_n$ from $1$ to $2N$ and the summation of $a_n$ from $1$ to $2N+1$ both converge as $N$ approaches infinity, but the summation of $a_n$ diverges?

The $2N$ and $2N+1$ part makes it seem like it must be a sequence where it does one thing when it's even and another when it's odd.

Or perhaps there's something where like everything from $1$ to $N$ is negative, and everything from $N$ to $2N$ is positive, making everything cancel out? But then I don't know how to explain why $2N+1$ would still converge, or whether a sequence like that exists (maybe if I make it piece-wise?)

And lastly I'm baffled by how one series would diverge as it approaches one infinity but as it approaches another infinity it can converge. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Find a sequence in which the odd terms converge, and the even terms converge, but the entire sequence doesn't converge.

> $$0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \ldots $$

If this sequence represents the partial sums to $N$ terms, then it satisfies our given condition.

**Hint:** A sequence that diverges does not necessarily converge to infinity. The above sequence diverges (does not converge).

**Hint:** The above sequence is the summations to $N$ terms. What would our original sequence look like?

> $$ 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots $$

In fact, given any such sequence in the first hint, we can always construct an original sequence which gives us our conclusion.

Comment: To what is this an answer? The summations to $2N$ and to $2N+1$ don't converge.

Comment: This doesn't quite work. We want the *summation* from 1 to $2N$ and from 1 to $2N+1$ to converge. This example can easily be adapted to work though. Edit: OK, it seems you intended your sequence as a hint not as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No, the sequence is the summations themselves. This is an answer to "how to approach a question like this", and explains the reasoning behind why things are done, rather than "By magic, this sequence works."

Comment: @JoshuaPepper I am explaining the process behind constructing the solution, working from the conditions of what is given. I didn't say that this sequence is the actual sequence.

Comment: Got it. The original presentation confused me.

Comment: @JoshuaPepper Yes, and that is why I use the phrase __Hint:__. I try and write my solutions in terms of hints, so that the OP works through and understands it, rather than just blindly copy without understanding (though the latter is what most people want).

Answer (score 2):

Pick your two favorite numbers, $a$ and $b$. Then consider the sum $$a+(b-a)+(a-b)+(b-a)+\cdots$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this works? I'm not quite seeing it.

Comment: Well, what do you get when you take just the 1st term? when you take the first 2 terms? the first 3? 4? $2N+1$? $2N$?

Comment: Oh ok so the sum for evens is the same and same for the odds, but it alternates if we're just going up to N. I get it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple : $a_i = (-1)^î$